# Increment a clock counter

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I have a clock counter which I need to increment by 1, the counter can be found at:

http://carbonexpert.lu12.com/private.php

So from: 6,204,988,466 to: 7,204,988,466 (but it still needs to count in the current manner)

This is a project I was given, I tried tinkering with the code but to no avail. Please help me

Comment: Unless I'm mistaking that's not 1 but 1 billion. Anyhow, it seems to be incrementing by 1 already. Should the starting value change?

Comment: So... you actually need to increment it by 1,000,000,000?

Comment: Can you share some of the code that you are currently trying to use?   It may be helpful to see what you're currently using.

Comment: yeah sorry, 1 billion. as mentioned i got the project from someone else, it was a headache trying to find part of the code: `http://carbonexpert.lu12.com/js/jquery.numerals.js, http://carbonexpert.lu12.com/js/counter.js, http://carbonexpert.lu12.com/js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js, http://carbonexpert.lu12.com/js/jquery.corner.js` those are the files which make the counter - the jquery.corner i believe its at the bottom. As mentioned it should read 7,***,***,*** instead of 6,***,***,***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `counter.js`, add this:

```
//                          VVV
current_population = string(1e9 + Math.round(secsSincePop * 2.48573 + 5979540016 - secsToday * 2.48573) + Math.round(secsToday * 4.41461) - Math.round(secsToday * 1.92888));
```

Then the current population box (which contains the amount of greenhouse gases...) will always contain a value that's 1 billion more than previously.